# What does 尽 mean and what tone does it have in 对我父母也极尽照顾?

Tags: meaning, tones

This question is about 尽 in this snippet:

> 不仅对我好，对我父母也极**尽**照顾，。。。
>   Bùjǐn duì wǒ hǎo, duì wǒ fùmǔ yě jí **[jìn/jǐn]** zhàogù, ...
>   <sub>[嫁给离婚带孩子的男人 我的生活只剩下两个字](http://www.guaixun.com/bdnews/content_214083_1.html), guaixun.com</sub>

I translate this to something like:

> Not only did he treat me well, he did his extreme utmost to look after my parents, ...

Here 尽 means something like "exhaust" or "utmost", but there appears to be a different meaning depending on the tone.  The Perapera Chinese Popup Dictionary shows the following:

[image: Perapera Chinese Popup Dictionary entry for 尽]

Both of these seem to make sense in this context.

**Question**: What does 尽 mean and what tone does it have in 对我父母也极尽照顾?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many dictionaries have a single entry for 极尽.

All with the pronunciation:

> jíjìn

**ABC**

> V.
>
> use to the utmost

**KEY**

> V
>
> 1 exhaust (one's ability, etc.), try one's best within the limits of
>
> 2 perform/fulfil to the utmost (a duty, etc.)
>
> 3 (before an adjective:) extremely, to the utmost

**PLC**

> VERB
>
> do one's utmost
>
> 极尽所能
> jíjìn suǒnéng
> do one’s best

Answer (score 1):

照顾 is a verb for "to look after" / "to take care"

极尽 is an adverb that modify 照顾

极 = maximally

尽 = exhaustively

极尽 (adv) = maximally, exhaustively; to the greatest extent

> "对我父母也极尽照顾" = "look after my parents to the greatest extent too"

More example for 极尽 (adv)

**极尽**侈华 = **extremely**(adv) extravagant(adj); extravagant to the greatest extent

Answer (score 1):

Well zdic has no word 极尽，but it has, for jin3 :力求达到最大限度 which seems to fit nicely.

不仅对我好，对我父母也极尽照顾，。。。
not only was he good to me, he also strove to look after my parents,

(Is this the same guy that locked up his kid?)

Then again, zdic also has for jin3 尽：极，最

Since the senses of jin1 and jin3 overlap, it is hard to tell from reading.

Answer (score 1):

The nuance can be found in the traditional characters.

盡 refers to the full extent, the highest limit to exhaustion.

儘, with its 亻 （人）radical, emphasizes the human agency in this limit. I.e., it's the full extent that a person can reach.

Hence,「儘早」, as soon as possible, not 「盡早」。The case of 「極盡照顧」is ambiguous--you're still talking about the person trying their best to take care of their parents. However, the emphasis is not on the person, but rather on the quality of care. Therefore, 極盡照顧 does not refer to “as much care as he is capable of giving", but rather "as much care as the concept of care itself allows"